# Tomcat looks different when installed using yum and apt-get

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat6

I just installed tomcat6 on Ubuntu using `apt-get` and on CentOs using `yum`. When I visit `www.domain.com:8080`, I get 2 different looking page.

Not that it really matters if just the visuals, but did I miss out a package or setting that causes this difference?

**CentOS**

[image]

**Ubuntu**

[image]

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on askubuntu.com or [sf]

Comment: Sorry, please help me move over admins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for the comment, btw the first screenshot is the java application containet tomcat and the second is the apache web server. Not the same software.